# get items from 'with' in eloquent query and display to blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

So i have this eloquent query

```
$categories = categories::all();
foreach($categories as $c):
    $c->items = item_categories::where('cat_id',$c->cat_id)->with('item')->with('item.item_images')->get();
endforeach;
```

and in my blade, I can display this part

```
with('item')
```

like doing

```
@foreach($categories as $c)
    @foreach($c->items as $i)
        {{ $i->item->item_name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

How about retrieving data from this part?

```
with('item.item_images')
```

I tried

```
@foreach($categories as $c)
    @foreach($c->items as $i)
        {{ $i->item->item->item_images->image_name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

but it gives me error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Any ideas, help please?

here's the 'categories' model

```
class categories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';

    public function item_category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\item_categories','cat_id','cat_id');
    }

}
```

and the 'item_categories' model

```
class item_categories extends Model{

    protected $table = "item_categories";

    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\items','item_id','item_id');
    }
    public function category(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\categories','cat_id','cat_id');
    }
}
```

and the 'items' model

```
class items extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';
    protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';

    public function item_images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\item_images','item_id','item_id');
    }
    public function item_categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\item_categories','item_id','item_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide ur model code so we can understand the realtions between models

Comment: please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going too deep. It looks like item_categories has an item, which has an item_image, so you just need to access it like this:

```
{{ $i->item->item_images->image_name }}
```

Since each item has many item_images, you need to iterate through it.

```
@foreach($i->item->item_images as $image)
     {{$image->image_name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried "{{ $i->item->item_images->image_name ? 'yes' : $i->item->item_images->image_name }} " but same error, but if I do this "{{ $i->item->item_images }}" It gives me the collections which indicate that there is a 'image_name' on it "[{"id":5,"image_name":"[x]sd.jpg","image_type":"jpg","created_at":"2016-11-15 02:41:54","updated_at":"2016-11-15 02:41:54"}]". Any ideas?

Comment: If `item_images` is a collection, then you need to iterate through it. I can update the code with that.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that too,

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your code is okay but item doesn't have item_image. Try checking if checking if $i->item->item->item_images is empty before trying to use the value

Comment: I tried "{{ $i->item->item_images->image_name ? 'yes' : $i->item->item_images->image_name }} " but same error, but if I do this "{{ $i->item->item_images }}" It gives me the collections which indicate that there is a 'image_name' on it "[{"id":5,"image_name":"[x]sd.jpg","image_type":"jpg","created_at":"2016-11-15 02:41:54","updated_at":"2016-11-15 02:41:54"}]". Any ideas?